# How to join 2 tables with inner and left outer join

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in MSSQL with the same structure T1 & T2. Both tables can INNER JOIN on Id but T2 may not contain the AccountId associated with the Id as in T1. 
    .

```
T1   Id   AccountId   Name            T2      Id   AccountId   Name       
     111  5555        John                    111  5555        John 
     122  5555        David                   133  5555        Sharon   
     133  5555        Sharon
```

Below is the code I tried but the result is not working?. 
    .

```
INSERT INTO T3
SELECT T1.Id,T1.AccountId,T1.Name
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 T2.Id = T1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN T1.AccountId = T2.AccountId
WHERE AccountId = 5555
```

The expected result would be to insert values that are not in T1 into T3

Comment: It sounds like you want T2 to contain the union of what is currently in T2 and what is in T1? If so, you could look into calculating the set-difference with EXCEPT and inserting those rows.

Comment: can you put a screen shot for the result expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `where` clause:

```
INSERT INTO T3(Id, AccountId, Name)
    SELECT T1.Id, T1.AccountId, T1.Name
    FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
         T2
         ON T2.Id = T1.id
    WHERE T2.AccountId IS NOT NULL;
```

Notes:

- Only one `LEFT JOIN` is necessary.  I don't know what the `INNER JOIN` is for.
- Every `JOIN` should be followed by an `ON` clause.
- You should list the columns when doing an `INSERT`.
- You need the `WHERE` to find non-matches.
- This query could also be written using `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're after:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (id int, AccountId int, [Name] varchar(6));
CREATE TABLE #T2 (id int, AccountId int, [Name] varchar(6));
CREATE TABLE #T3 (id int, AccountId int, [Name] varchar(6));
INSERT INTO #T1
VALUES (111,5555,'John  '),
       (122,5555,'David '),
       (133,5555,'Sharon');
INSERT INTO #T2
VALUES (111,5555,'John  '),
       (133,5555,'Sharon');

INSERT INTO #T3 (id, AccountId, [Name])
SELECT T1.id,
       T1.AccountId,
       T1.[Name]
FROM #T1 T1
     LEFT JOIN #T2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.id
WHERE T2.id IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM #t3;

DROP TABLE #T1;
DROP TABLE #T2;
DROP TABLE #T3;
```